# First homology group of the general linear group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

The abelianization of the general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, defined by $$GL(n,\mathbb{R})^{ab} := GL(n,\mathbb{R})/[GL(n,\mathbb{R}), GL(n,\mathbb{R})],$$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$. This follows from the fact that $[GL(n,\mathbb{R}),GL(n,\mathbb{R})] \cong SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, so that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})^{ab} \cong \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

Since for any group $G$, the homology group $H_1(G;\mathbb{Z}) \cong G^{ab}$, it turns out that $H_1(GL(n,\mathbb{R});\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

I wonder if it possible to obtain this result by directly computing $H_1(GL(n,\mathbb{R});\mathbb{Z})$ as the quotient $Z_1(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))/B_1(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$ of 1-cycles by 1-boundaries.

> What do $C_1$, $Z_1$ and $B_1$ look like for $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$? Is a direct computation of $H_1(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$ possible?

In case this question turns out to be too elementary for MO, I apologize in advance. In that case I will quickly move my post to MSE.

Comment: try to copy the proof of the fact that $H_1$ is the Abelianization in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This more of a comment, but here it goes anyway.

Following Brown's book *[Cohomology of Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9327-6)* on page 36, we see that with respect to the standard resolution and any group $G$: $$C_2(G)\xrightarrow{\partial}C_1(G)\xrightarrow{0}\mathbb{Z}\to 0,$$ where $\partial[g|h]=[h]-[gh]+[g]$.

Consequently, $Z_1(G)=C_1(G)=\{[g]\ |\ g\in G\} $ and $B_1(G)=\{[h]-[gh]+[g]\ |\ h,g\in G\}$.

So $H_1(G)\cong G/[G,G]$.  I am not sure what more you could expect in any special case of this.

In the case of a complex reductive (affine algebraic) group $G$, the quotient $G/[G,G]$ will always be isomorphic to an algebraic torus (isomorphic to a product of $\mathrm{GL}_1$'s), but that has nothing to do with group cohomology (it's the central isogeny theorem; see Milne's book *[Algebraic Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-groups/48D122BAEC63C2B70304E20F34482C8F)* for example).  A special case of this general fact is $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ where $G/[G,G]\cong \mathbb{C}^*$.  The fact that you get $\mathbb{R}^*$ for $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is analogous to this case ([in fact it is true for any field](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup_of_general_linear_group_is_special_linear_group)).

Comment: It's true that, algebraically, $G/[G, G]$ is a torus; but does it follow that $G(\mathbb R)/[G(\mathbb R), G(\mathbb R)]$ is always the group of $\mathbb R$-points of a torus?

Comment: @LSpice With respect to $\mathbb{R}$-loci, this is true at least for $GL_n$, which is all I was saying since that was the case of interest of the OP.  The more general statement I mentioned, $G/DG\cong T/(T\cap DG),$ can be found in Milne's book on Algebraic Groups (Chapter 22 in the version on his website).

Comment: Indeed, I agree that it's true for $\operatorname{GL}_n$.  At the risk of belabouring the point, what I meant to say was that the algebraic-group equality $G/DG \cong T/(T \cap DG)$ that you mention doesn't obviously (or not obviously to me) imply that $G(\mathbb R)/D(G(\mathbb R)) \cong (T/(T \cap DG))(\mathbb R)$, which seemed to be your claim.  (Note particularly the denominator $D(G(\mathbb R)) = [G(\mathbb R), G(\mathbb R)]$, as opposed to $(DG)(\mathbb R)$.)

Comment: @LSpice As I mentioned, I do not think I made that claim (I apologize if my use of language is causing confusion).  I made the general claim in the cases where the central isogeny theorem holds, for example $\mathbb{C}$, and then said that the reason one gets $\mathbb{R}^*$ in the case of interest of the OP "is a real version of this".

Comment: (cont.) That phrase, to me at least, is saying it is analogous, but not precisely the same thing.  And it is analogous.  Comparing the isomorphism for $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ case to the $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ case one sees that $G/DG$ arises in both cases the same way (via the determinant and the first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: Anyway, I will edit my answer to make this more clear.